# I have two classes and there is a association between them and we make an object array

Tags: java

I have this code and  I can develop it to make two object from class Person and they have the same Address (  object class)
the code :

```
class Address {
}
 class Person {
   //Person has-a Address

public Address[]  address;
   public Person(Address[] address) {
     this.address = address;
     }
   // Other code goes here
   }
 public Person(Address[] address) {
    this.address = address;
}
 // Other code goes here
      }
```

how can I create array object from class ?

Comment: how can I create array object from class ?

Comment: Eran thnx :) 
but can you help me more

Comment: I need two create two Person have the same address and have another  different address

Comment: my friends, If I have to edit or delete  the shared Address what happen?

Comment: can you write the code for me plz

Comment: to add address to person and edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Persons, each with one shared Address and one unique Address :

```
Address[] addArr1 = new Address[2];
Address[] addArr2 = new Address[2];
addArr1[0] = new Address (...);
addArr2[0] = addArr1[0]; // the shared Address
addArr1[1] = new Address (...); // unique Address
addArr2[1] = new Address (...); // unique Address
Person p1 = new Person (addArr1);
Person p2 = new Person (addArr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Address {
}
class Person {
    //Person has-a Address

    public Address[]  address;
    public Person(Address[] address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    // Other code goes here
}

Person[] persons = new Person[2];
Address[] address = new Address[100];
persons[0] = new Person(address);
person[1] = new Person(address);
```